# glTexSubImage2D does not update texture

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg, textures

I am writing video program with ffmpeg and opengl. Generate 2 textures and swap them when paint.
the code of DrawFirstFrame invoked once is

```
 avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,
                              &packet);

        // Did we get a video frame?
        if(frameFinished)
        {
            f++;

            pFrameRGB=avcodec_alloc_frame();
            //Allocate memory for the raw data we get when converting.
            uint8_t *buffer;
            int numBytes;
            numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
            buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

            //Associate frame with our buffer
            avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                           pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
            pFrameRGB->linesize[0]= pCodecCtx->width*3; // in case of rgb4  one plane
            struct SwsContext* swsContext = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                            pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                            pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC,
                                            NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (swsContext == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize the conversion context!\n");
                exit(1);
            };

            sws_scale(swsContext, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
            current_Vtex=&VideoTexture;

            glGenTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, VideoTexture);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            //  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);

            glGenTextures(1, &VideoTexture2);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, VideoTexture2);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            //  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
            //glDeleteTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
            GLenum err;
            while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
            {
                cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << endl;
            }
           av_free(buffer);
        }
    }

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);

    if (f>1) break;
}
```

then in a cycle

```
if (token.IsSameAs("frame"))
                {
                    this->panel->DrawNextFrame();
                    wxPaintEvent evt;
                    this->panel->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(evt);
                    GetThread()->Sleep(500);
                    token=tkz.GetNextToken();
                    token.ToLong(&lastframe);
                    wxCriticalSectionLocker lock(*CSect);
                    this->fram->Clear();
                }
```

DrawNextFrame() code is here, trying to update the textures generated in DrawFirstFrame

```
    void BasicGLPane::DrawNextFrame()
{
int f=1;
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
    {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
        {


            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &FrameFinished,
                                  &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if(FrameFinished)
            {
                f++;
                 pFrameRGB=avcodec_alloc_frame();
                //Allocate memory for the raw data we get when converting.
                uint8_t *buffer;
                int numBytes;
                numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
                buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

                //Associate frame with our buffer
                avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                               pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
                pFrameRGB->linesize[0]= pCodecCtx->width*3; // in case of rgb4  one plane
                struct SwsContext* swsContext = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                                                pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                                pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC,
                                                NULL, NULL, NULL);
                if (swsContext == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize the conversion context!\n");
                    exit(1);
                };

                sws_scale(swsContext, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                //glGenTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
                if ((*current_Vtex)==VideoTexture) current_Vtex = &VideoTexture2;else current_Vtex = &VideoTexture;
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (*current_Vtex));
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
                glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
                //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
                //glDeleteTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
                GLenum err;
                while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
                {
                    cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << endl;
                }

            }
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        if (f>1) break;
    }

av_free(pFrameRGB);
Refresh();
}
```

Render Function renders  (*current_Vtex) in a quad.

```
if ((*current_Vtex) != 0)
        {
        GLfloat z = 0;
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glPushMatrix();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (*current_Vtex));
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, z);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(Width, 0,z);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(Width, Height,z);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(0, Height,z);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }

    wxCriticalSectionLocker lock(*CSect);
    this->fram->render();

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers();
```

THe problem is that the picture on screen doesn't update (why?) only shows what was generated in DrawFirstFrame. I surely know that the program swaps textures when paint.

Comment: Don't call `glFlush (...)` before `SwapBuffers (...)`. WGL ***already*** flushes the pipeline when it swaps buffers. In fact, if you use the GDI (software) implementation it does a full `glFinish (...)` first. This is not related to your problem, but something you should be aware of. As for your actual problem, did you remember to clear the depth buffer?

Comment: The other possibility is that you are decoding the frames in a separate thread from the thread you created your OpenGL context in. I get this impression from this statement in your code: `GetThread()->Sleep(500);`. If you want to decode video in a separate thread from the one you're drawing in, you should double buffer your textures and enable context sharing (e.g. `wglShareLists (...)`) so that you can do this correctly with minimal synchronization overhead.

Comment: Yes I call DrawNextFrame in separate thread, i don't unsderstand what should i add to my code

Comment: I changed My code , so now it works fine. But it have some another bug, the free from texture screen - its  color changes whith the texture color